# C: Pipe: How to pass a dynamic int array using pipe correctly

Tags: c, pointers, pipe, malloc

I tried to write a dynamic allocated int array in several child processes, and read them in parent process using pipe, but the result is like [-15236548, 37526, -15236548, 37526,0,0,0,0,0,0], it looks like the addresses are read instead of the real values[1,1,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,1]. I am really struggling in it for the whole day, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

The child process are 10, they would first write an array each, and after all of them are done, parent process reads the 10 array.

```
int *getArr(){
    int * arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) *100);
    //do something
    return arr1;
}

//write values to pipe
void write_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len){
    char *p = buffer;
    while(len>0){
        size_t wlen = write(fd, p, len);
        if(wlen <= 0)
            exit(0);
        p += wlen;
        len -= wlen;
    }
}

// read values from pipe
void read_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len){
    char *p = buffer;
    while(len>0){
        size_t rlen = read(fd, p, len);
        if(rlen <= 0)
            exit(0);
        p += rlen;
        len -= rlen;
    }
}

// pass values, and get it ready to be wrote
void write_ints(int fd, int *p, int len){
    write_check(fd, p, len * sizeof(*p));
}

// allocate memory for fetching values
void read_ints(int fd, int *p, int len){
    p = malloc(len * sizeof(*p));
    read_check(fd, p, len* sizeof(*p));
}


int main(){
    int len = 100;
    int *arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    int *fds = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10 * 2);

    // child processes write values to pipe
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0){
            // do something
            arr1 = getArr();
            write_ints(fd[i*2+1], &arr1, len);
        }
    }
    // parent process reads values 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        // do something
        read_ints(fd[i*2], &arr1, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing you shouldn't be passing `&arr1` to your functions, since `arr1` is already an `int *`.

Comment: Also, I assume you didn't copy-paste the code into this question, because there are some typos, such as `int *P` in the argument list for `read_ints`, and `sozeif` instead of `sizeof`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Thanks, I fixed the typo. So what should I pass to the function?  I tried `arr1` and `*arr` they were all wrong.

Comment: `arr1` is correct given the function prototype.  The rest of your program doesn't make much sense, though.  You `malloc` your array in main.  Then promptly throw away that reference to data and assign `getArr()` to it, which `malloc`s even more data.  Then you pass that array into `write_ints()` which again promptly throws away that memory to `malloc` a new chunk of memory.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I was using `fork` for getting several `arr1` in child processes and read that to parent process. I think I should complete my code a bit...

Comment: @ChristianGibbons  I tried `arr1` where I got `segmentation fault`.

Comment: How often do you think`fork()` is going to be called?

Comment: @wildplasser 10?

Comment: With all the many child processes attempting to write things to a single filehandle, there's no guarantee the parent will get an entire child's array, or even an entire `int` representation, all at once. Probably better to use a different pipe for each child.

Comment: @aschepler I did that, I just didn't write it here in this minimum version, I would add this part into it for better understanding

Comment: Okay, but then that mistake in the question's code is a distraction from giving a useful answer. This is why a [mre] is helpful - and this is not Reproducible if it has bugs other than the issue you want to ask about.

Comment: @aschepler Got it, I revised the code, hope it is now easier to understand

Comment: Consider using [JSON](http://json.org/) or [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) for communication between processes. In most cases, it will make your life simpler. See also [SWIG](http://swig.org/). Read [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) or [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void read_ints(int fd, int *p, int len){
    p = malloc(len * sizeof(*p));
    read_check(fd, p, len* sizeof(*p));
}
```

This function is unusable. You pass it a pointer, which it ignores. It then allocates some memory, reads some integers into that memory, and does nothing with the pointer to that memory leaving the caller no way to access the read values.

If this function is going to allocate memory, it needs to return a pointer to the memory it allocated. If this function is going to receive a pointer to the memory it's going to read the integers into, then it should read the integers into the supplied buffer and not allocate its own.

Your code would be much easier to debug if it had comments. Looking at this function, I cannot tell what it's supposed to do and I see conflicting information in the code. Is it supposed to allocate a buffer to read integers into or is it supposed to be supplied a pointer to the buffer to read into? A comment would clear that up.

You cannot count on your code to document your intentions yet because your code isn't yet good enough to do that. So you need to use comments so that other people can tell what you meant to do, not just what you actually did.

Comment: This function was for allocating memory. But it did indicate the size of array, doesn't it?

Comment: You are right! since I allocated the memory in the main function, no need to allocate it again and even to another pointer

Comment: @heisthere If this function is allocating memory, why doesn't it return a pointer to the memory it allocated?

Comment: I thought the passed value `int *p` and the allocated value `p` could be the same element, but which is not

Comment: Since the value isn't known until the call to `malloc` returns, how could the passed in value (passed in by the called *before* the call to `malloc`) be the same as the value returned by `malloc`?

Answer (score 0):

expected int * but argument is int ** error is due to passing &arr1 .address of a pointer is a double pointer.just pass arr1 (in both write_ints and read_ints) and you wont get that error.

Comment: I completed the code, I tried `arr1` which got `segmentation fault`.